# XQL vs. XQuery vs.

Tags: terminology, xml

I am studying some standards and tools for XML, but I confused with some terms and standards and their differences

What is [XQL](http://www.ibiblio.org/xql/xql-proposal.html#Hierarchy%20and%20Filters)? It seems the same as [XQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery) and somehow even similar to [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)?

Are XQL and XQuery the same?
Are there other similar [even deprecated] standards?

Comment: Some people, when they see someone else presented with a problem, think "I know, I'll use a clever variation on a Jamie Zawinski regex quote."

Comment: @RobertHarvey: You do know that Jamie Zawinski got that from an even earlier quote about a UNIX tool?  I don't remember if it was Awk or Sed, or something like that, but either way, I'm simply carrying on a tradition with an honorable history. ;-)

Comment: @Ahmad in the document (from '99) you linked on XQL: "The basic constructs of XQL correspond directly to the basic structures of XML, and XQL is closely related to XPath, the common locator syntax used by XSL and XPointers." And from the standard document for [XQuery](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/), "XQuery is derived from an XML query language called Quilt [Quilt], which in turn borrowed features from several other languages, including XPath 1.0 [XML Path Language (XPath) Version 1.0], XQL [XQL], XML-QL [XML-QL], SQL [SQL], and OQL [ODMG]." Please make sure you read the research you link.

Comment: @MichaelT your comment could be the answer! I noticed later the article is from 1999 but there was no mention of XQL or even (Quilt) in [XQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery) in Wikipedia, The relations you made and the history is not easily found there

Comment: @MasonWheeler Regardless of your common part with Zawinski, if the second part (the code) is you own! I must say, THAT is the clever part ;)

Comment: @Ahmad: Thanks. And yes, I came up with the "XM-Mess" version of that old joke myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference beween XQL and XQuery is that XQL is dead. It was pretty well stillborn. It influenced the design of XQuery but it was never significant in its own right.